# Ubuntu as a main OS

Tags: partitioning

I installed ubuntu 14 lts. I totally removed windows OS.
But i not created partition on my 360 GB lenovo laptop.
Now i have create another partition after installation !
How to create ??

please help me in this regard.

Comment: What partition you did not create and why?

Answer (score 1):

Use a program called Gparted and follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions

Answer (score -2):

type in your terminal

> gparted

guessing you are new to the Ubuntu and using BIOS do the following

1)assign 7-8 gb for root partition of Ubuntu

2)assign 2-3 gb for swap space

3)make third partition for personal usage (format can NTFS or ext4)

4)if you planning to make yet another partition, make it an extended one, within which you can make unlimited logical partitions

NOTE: size of the root and swap space can be anything according to your need.. this is just a suggestion to be beginners and BIOS users

Hope this helps...

Comment: Why format to NTFS if there is no Windows?

Comment: yeah  i understand.. i thought to mention it incase if he is confused with the fs... i stated both can work with linux...

Comment: This answer can really confuse people. And almost everything else is wrong.

Comment: can you pls state the "almost" part of it... even i'll something to learn here

Comment: First of all it is not clear what OP is asking, so this question makes no sense. It is not clear what you cal "root partition". 7-8 GB is too small anyway, etc.

Comment: i think root partition is the partion where you mount "/"... am i not right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34804/discussion-between-juggernaut1996-and-pilot6).

Comment: About the only thing that was clear in the question is that he already has Ubuntu installed, so it makes no sense to suggest creating a root partition, which already exists and is where `gparted` itself is installed.

Comment: i had answered this keeping in mind that he very new to this environment... i thought it should be mentioned for everybody... sonce this is always a dilemma of how much space to be given and how to work with extended partition